# Error: To accepting cookies (raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:)

Tags: python, selenium

```
File "C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\python-virtual-environments\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, 
in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried some recommendations from related issues to accept the cookies but it didn't help me. At first, it couldn't find the element for cookies, that's why I added EC, but now it raises an error. Please, help me, how can I handle the Exception. I have tried the locator both with xpath and css-selector too.

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
class aquamobiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://www.cosmote.gr/eshop/browse/Mobile-phones/All-Smartphones/-/N-x4fndm'
        self.country='HU'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT='Included'
        self.shipping = 'N/A'
        self.Pre_PromotionPrice ='N/A'
        self.color ='N/A'
    def aqua(self):
        driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
        driver.get(self.url)
        today = date.today()
        driver.maximize_window() 
        time.sleep(5)
        '''cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Acceptance')]")         
        cookies.click()
        print("cookies accepted")'''
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Aποδοχή')]")))
        time.sleep(4)
        element12 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Aποδοχή')]")#.click()
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element12).click().perform();
        print("cookies accepted")
aqua_gr=aquamobiles()
aqua_gr.aqua()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple web elements with the text that you are using, even classes are duplicated for few elements.

try this **xpath** :

**In code :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[contains(@class, 'js-close-modal-cookiePackage')])[2]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several buttons matching `//button[contains(text(),'Aποδοχή')]` locator on that page. But only 1 of them is visible. To locate and click it you can use this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'100')]//button[contains(@class,'acceptAll')]")))
```